# Can you define multiple different iterators for a Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a very simple Tree class:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value_ = None, children_ = None):
        self.value = value_
        self.children = children_
```

I'd like to be able to perform both DFS and BFS traversal with a simple loop, i.e.:

```
t = Tree()
# ...fill tree...

for node in t:
    print(node.value)
```

In C++, for example, you can have multiple types of iterators - so I could define both a DFS and a BFS iterator and use one or the other depending on what type of traversal I wanted to do. Is this possible to do in Python?

Comment: `Tree` is not a class. It is a function. Classes are defined like: `class Tree(object):`

Comment: @ozgur: Typo - thanks for catching!

Comment: How would you specify which type of iteration you want to do in a particular case?

Comment: @BrenBarn: That's pretty much what I'm asking. My understanding of C++ (which admittedly may be flawed) is that I could do that by defining two different types of iterators and then using one or the other, e.g. `TreeDFSIterator it = Tree.begin()` vs `TreeBFSIterator it = Tree.begin()`.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: There was a major typo initially (I actually had written `def` instead of `class`) - ozgur was right :)

Comment: @tonysdg notice that in your C++ examples, you're *constructing* new iterators by calling the constructor implicitly. In Python the very same would have to be written `it = TreeDFSIterator(tree.begin())` and `it = TreeBFSIterator(tree.begin())`, and that is also doable. In Python, objects have type, but since names are not objects (unlike in C++), the names themselves do not have types.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I never even thought of it that way - for some reason, C++ iterators were magical devices in my mind haha. That makes a lot of sense - thank you!!

Comment: also, the STL approach is more generic. You can have any class that does not need to subclass from any other particular class, just provide the given interface, and it would be iterable using these iterators. If your interface is that a node must have `value`, `left` and `right` as attributes, you could take the methods from niemmi's answer into functions that take a `node`, rename them to `tree_dfs_iterator` and `tree_bfs_iterator`, and they'd be generic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have multiple methods returning iterators and have the 'default'  one as [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__). Below is a simple binary tree where 'default' iterator does DFS and which additionally supports BFS with separate method:

```
from collections import deque

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left:
            for x in self.left:
                yield x

        yield self.value

        if self.right:
            for x in self.right:
                yield x

    def bfs(self):
        q = deque([self])
        while q:
            x = q.popleft()
            if x:
                yield x.value
                q.extend([x.left, x.right])
```

Short example of usage:

```
root = Tree(2)
root.left = Tree(1)
root.right = Tree(4)
root.right.left = Tree(3)
root.right.right = Tree(5)

print list(root) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print list(root.bfs()) # [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write separate methods on your class for the two types of iteration.  These could for instance be generators that yield values in whatever order you want.  You would then write something like:

```
for node in t.depth_first():
    # ...

for node in t.breadth_first():
    # ...
```